# Correlation scatterplots using different factors in a data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, ggpubr

Apologies in advance if the title was not clear. I have a DF `RatingScores` as follows:

```
head(RatingScores)

    PP Condition QuoteType Rating Correct
1  pp1 Disfluent        BS   3.15       7
2  pp1 Disfluent     Motiv   4.15       7
3 pp10 Disfluent     Motiv   3.75       6
4 pp10 Disfluent        BS   1.45       6
5 pp11    Fluent     Motiv   4.45       6
6 pp11    Fluent        BS   3.50       6
```

My goal is to perform a correlational analysis between `Rating` and `Correct`, but I would require the `Rating` from each `Condition` * `QuoteType` factors. For example, correlating the `Rating` from `Disfluent*BS` with `Correct` (i.e. using lines 1 and 4). My second goal is to then plot these correlations on a scatterplot, with each correlation line on the graph.

My only solution so far has been to subset the data accordingly and then plot individual graphs using `ggscatter`, but I am not able to overlay them over each other using `par(new=TRUE)`.

This is how I have subset the data so far:

```
DBS=subset(RatingScores,RatingScores$Condition=="Disfluent"&RatingScores$QuoteType=="BS")
FBS=subset(RatingScores,RatingScores$Condition=="Fluent"&RatingScores$QuoteType=="BS")
DMo=subset(RatingScores,RatingScores$Condition=="Disfluent"&RatingScores$QuoteType=="Motiv")
FMo=subset(RatingScores,RatingScores$Condition=="Fluent"&RatingScores$QuoteType=="Motiv")
```

And then plot each one like so:

```
ggscatter(DMo, x = "Rating", y = "Correct", 
                add = "reg.line",point = F,color = "green", conf.int = F, 
                cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson", title = "Disfluent Mo",
                xlab = "Rating", ylab = "CRT Score")
```

If there is a more efficient and clearer way of doing this, I would highly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
ggscatter(RatingScores, x = "Rating", y = "Correct", 
          add = "reg.line",point = F,color = "green", conf.int = F, 
          cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson", title = "Disfluent Mo",
          xlab = "Rating", ylab = "CRT Score") +
  facet_wrap(Condition ~ QuoteType)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Almost - is there a way to overlay the graphs over each other, so that I have one graph but with four lines? The `x` and `y` axes are the same for all graphs, hence my wish to have them all in one. I'd normally use `par(new=TRUE)` to accomplish this but I haven't had any luck in this regard.

Comment: try to do `facet_wrap(Condition ~ QuoteType, ncol = 4)` or  `facet_wrap(Condition ~ QuoteType, nrow = 4)`

Comment: Thank you. This brought me close to what I wanted but I managed to achieve my goal by merging `Condition` and `QuoteType` into one grouping variable and then used `ggscatter` normally with the addition of `stat_cor`. Wasn't aware of `facet_wrap` until now, so that's something new for me.